# Best way to output a grid of bitmap tiles in Android?

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android game where the main screen is similar to Words with Friends- a grid of multiple bitmap tiles. The problem I have is with scrolling (up, down, left, right) and pinch to zoom.

Right now I'm using a surfaceview to output the tiles. To implement scrolling, I calculate the difference between touch_down and touch_up, shift the index of the top left tile accordingly, and then redraw the grid.

The problem with this is that I have to wait until the user releases their touch to move the screen, instead of a smooth scroll. I haven't implemented pinch to zoom yet but I would run into the same problem there as well.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just curious: can you use a simple GridView with each cell being your tile?  Then the scrolling would be taken care of automatically.

Comment: BTW, just a note: if you have zoom functionality but require "pinch to zoom", please do provide an alternative method of zooming (zoom control maybe?)  There are plenty of lower-spec android devices out there (I have one as my main phone) with resistive screens that do not support multi-touch.

Comment: I actually hadn't considered a GridView, I'll look into that. The only problem I can think of is that I wouldn't be able to add buttons or animations on top of the grid if I wanted to. For example, dragging and dropping a tile from one position to another.
Also, thanks for your suggestion about having multiple options for zooming. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: You can do anything you like with the GridView.  Each cell doesn't have to be an image - it can be any view, for example, a button that takes up the entire cell and has background set to the image of the tile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` which gets fired off every time the user moves their finger on the screen instead of `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` or `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` which only get fired on the touch down and touch up.

Just keep track of the pointer position between `ACTION_MOVE` events and use that information to move the game board.

Comment: Sweet, I'll use that instead of action_down/up. But, another problem I might have is that I'd be redrawing dozens of images many times per second as they move their finger. This would probably be very laggy. Is there a way I could copy all the small tiles into one large image and just move that instead? Thanks.

Comment: drawing dozens of images will probably take about the same amount of time as drawing one large image.  The best option would be to use OpenGL ES